# Multiple query filters on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently trying to filter a sheet using several options, I managed to make two queries, now I want to merge the two, I just can't do it.

**I managed to do a data validation for the names, using this code:**

```
=QUERY('Respostas Avaliação'!A1:K;"SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "&SE(D2="Todos os Mestres";"";" AND D = '"&D2&"' ");1)
[Image][1]
```

**And I did a query to be able to filter by date:**

```
=QUERY('Respostas Avaliação'!A:K; "select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K WHERE A >= date '" & TEXTO(G2;"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND A <= date '" & TEXTO(H2;"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'";1) [Image][2]
```

I'm really new to any kind of coding, is there a way to merge the two, so that I can make a single sheet to filter every thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY('Respostas Avaliação'!A:K; 
 "where A >= date '"&TEXT(G2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date '"&TEXT(H2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"&
 IF(D2="Todos os Mestres";;" and D = '"&D2&"'"); 1)
```